# translate3d vs left/right when positioning elements on touchstart/touchmove

Tags: javascript, html, performance, tablet, acceleration

I am implementing functionality to make elements movable by touch on a page for an Android tablet. To test manually the most performant way to move elements I have created a function which is attached to two divs and for first it changes its position by assigning `box.style.left` and `box.style.top` and for another by assigning `-webkit-transform:translate3d(x,y,z)` property.

When I am trying it on a tablet, it doesn't seem like two divs have any difference in performance so I wonder if I should prefer one method over another one?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7z6p/).

Comment: I think translate3d is faster because it uses the GPU. See http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d